# How to change fill colour of verbatimTextOutput

Tags: r, shiny

Is there anyway to change the fill colour of the `verbatimTextOutput`? Basically I want this to stand out from the other sections. The below is an illustration figure to show why it doesn't stand out with the default settings. And at the bottom is a simple example with 1 `verbatimTextOutput`

[image]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("test"),
      width = 2
    ),
    mainPanel(
      "",
      width = 8
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test = renderText("Hi")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your custom CSS for the `pre` elements (`verbatimTextOutput`). You can add CSS as `.css` file or inline. Below is an example using an inline CSS.

```R
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      /* this will affect all the pre elements */
      pre {
        color: red;
        background-color: #5ef4fb;
      }
      /* this will affect only the pre elements under the class myclass */
      .myclass pre {
        color: black;
        background-color: #d6860f;
        font-weight: bolder;
      }"))
  ),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("test1"),
      div(class = "myclass",
        verbatimTextOutput("test2")
      ),
      width = 2
    ),
    mainPanel(
      "",
      width = 8
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test1 = renderText("Hi")
  output$test2 = renderText("Hello")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Really love your example as you included 2 examples, one for all the pre elements and the other for myclass.

Comment: Glad it works for you. If you think it answers your question, you could accept the answer by clicking on the check mark.